Chatter Email Notifications & LWR Community
We have an LWR portal with a custom chatter feed component, it also allows users to select a select a digest frequency.
When a notification that a post has been made to the chatter group is received, the email contains a link to view the post.
However, when clicking on the link we are either taken to an invalid page in the community (if the user does not have access to Salesforce core) or a visualforce site page with the chatter post (if the user does have access to core).
I understand that we can't modify the link in the notification email without building our own solution but has anyone else had a similar issue or found a workaround?
I've found that we can use a URL redirect which solves half of the problem for users without access to core, and redirect them to a generic page in the portal but this doesn't work for the vf site unfortunately as the source URL needs to be relative and the link from the email has a number of variables.

This question is similar to: Chatter email links - Community. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
